# Data is not getting populated using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to populate the Data to the RV. If i do it using a Custom Adapter (Traditional Adapter for RV). 
The data is getting populated. But i want to use the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. So that i can reduce some of the Boiler Plate code. while Implementing i get `Failed to bounce to type` Error.

**JSON From Firebase**

```
{
  "subscriptions" : {
    "obama@gmsil,com" : {
      "-KDnfjROKeFAL9wccsxY" : {
        "category" : "Mobility",
        "goal" : "afternoon body weight workout",
        "length" : 1,
        "title" : "Afternoon HiiT",
        "weeks" : {
          "week1" : [ "High Knees", "Squats", "Lunges", "Diamond Push-ups", "Lying Triceps Lifts" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Program.java**

```
public class Program {
    private String title;

    private String goal;

    private String category;

    private int length;

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> weeks;

    public Program() {
    }

    public Program(String title, String goal,  String category, int length, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> weeks) {
        this.title = title;
        this.goal = goal;
        this.category = category;
        this.length = length;
        this.weeks = weeks;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getGoal() {
        return goal;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }
    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> getweeks() {
        return weeks;
    }    
}
```

**Fragment Code**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_latest, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Program, ProgramVH>(Program.class, R.layout.program_item, ProgramVH.class, mRef) {
            @Override
            public void populateViewHolder(final ProgramVH programViewHolder, Program mProgram, int position) {
                programViewHolder.setName(program.getTitle());
                programViewHolder.level.setText(program.getLength());

            }
        };
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        FetchData();
        return v;
    }

public void FetchData(){

        mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot programSnapshot : userSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            program = programSnapshot.getValue(Program.class);
                            Log.e("VH", program.getTitle());  // Title is getting printed
                        }
                    }
                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mAdapter.cleanup();
    }
```

**ViewHolder**

```
public static class ProgramVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected ImageView header;
        protected TextView title;
        protected TextView level;

        public ProgramVH(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.header = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.coverImage);
            this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            this.level = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.level);
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            title.setText(name);
        }
    }
```

**STACK TRACE**

> 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/VH: Afternoon HiiT
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.sam, PID: 5717
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime: com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:185)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:161)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:150)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:190)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5465)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5498)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4735)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4611)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1988)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1384)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1347)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3026)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2903)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3277)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1087)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:797)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.layoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:63)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:126)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1139)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:810)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1684)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:122)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1139)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:810)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1183)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15686)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5039)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
>   03-30 08:55:19.045 5717-5717/com.android.sam E/AndroidRuntime:  at android.view.View

**UPDATE**

The data is getting populated if i use the below `ref`

```
Firebase mRef = new Firebase("https://arulnadhan.firebaseio.com/").child("subscriptions/obama@gmsil,com");
```

But it doesn't work when i use the below `ref` & the FetchData() Method!

```
Firebase mRef = new Firebase("https://arulnadhan.firebaseio.com/subscriptions");

public void FetchData(){

        mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot programSnapshot : userSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            program = programSnapshot.getValue(Program.class);
                            Log.e("VH", program.getTitle());  // Title is getting printed
                        }
                    }
                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

**JSON under subscriptions node **

```
{
  "arulndhan@gmail,com" : {
    "-KDnhRwHjssOejrqyenP" : {
      "category" : "Strength",
      "goal" : "This workout can be done while on the phone!",
      "length" : 1,
      "title" : "Hello Workouts",
      "weeks" : {
        "week1" : [ "High Knees", "Jumping Jacks", "Wall sit", "Pushups", "Sit-ups", "Step ups", "Squats", "Tricep dips on chair", "Plank", "High Knees running in place", "Lunges", "Pushup and rotation", "Side plank (alternate per round)", "Alternating Push-Up Plank", "Chest Expander", "Diamond Push-ups", "Dive Bomber Push-ups", "Butt Kickers", "Lying Triceps Lifts", "One Arm Side Push-up", "Overhead Arm Clap", "Overhead Press", "Power Circles", "Push-up and Rotation", "T Push-ups", "Reverse Plank", "Spiderman Push-up", "T Raise", "Tricep Dips", "Wall Push-ups", "Wide Arm Push-ups", "Burpees" ]
      }
    },
    "-KDni3TN4NMyGXePyp92" : {
      "category" : "Strength",
      "goal" : "This workout can be done by a BABUJI",
      "length" : 1,
      "title" : "Indian Workouts",
      "weeks" : {
        "week1" : [ "Diamond Pushups", "Jackknives", "Plyo Lunges", "Plyo Squats", "Single leg plank (alternate per round)", "Plyo Lunges", "Pushup and rotation", "Weighted side plank (alternate per round)", "Alternating Push-Up Plank", "Chest Expander", "Diamond Push-ups", "Dive Bomber Push-ups", "One Arm Side Push-up", "Overhead Press", "Push-up and Rotation", "T Push-ups", "Spiderman Push-up", "Wide Arm Push-ups", "Burpee Pushups" ]
      }
    }
  },
  "obama@gmsil,com" : {
    "-KDnfjROKeFAL9wccsxY" : {
      "category" : "Mobility",
      "goal" : "afternoon body weight workout",
      "length" : 1,
      "title" : "Afternoon HiiT",
      "weeks" : {
        "week1" : [ "High Knees", "Squats", "Lunges", "Diamond Push-ups", "Lying Triceps Lifts" ]
      }
    },
    "-KDps90Dn6XtJc6Co00b" : {
      "category" : "Strength",
      "goal" : "goal",
      "length" : 1,
      "title" : "title",
      "weeks" : {
        "week1" : [ "Diamond Pushups", "Jackknives", "Plyo Lunges", "Plyo Squats", "Single leg plank (alternate per round)", "Plyo Lunges", "Pushup and rotation", "Weighted side plank (alternate per round)", "Alternating Push-Up Plank", "Chest Expander", "Diamond Push-ups", "Dive Bomber Push-ups", "One Arm Side Push-up", "Overhead Press", "Push-up and Rotation", "T Push-ups", "Spiderman Push-up", "Wide Arm Push-ups", "Burpee Pushups" ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` *inside* `populateViewHolder()`? This doesn't make any sense to me. i highly recommend that you take a few steps back and *first* follow the [FirebaseUI codelab](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/codelabs/chat).

Comment: I have followed the chatMessage Example. But after seeing this answer i have changed it inside `populateViewHolder()` http://stackoverflow.com/a/34561726/2781359

Comment: Each user under `https://arulnadhan.firebaseio.com/` has subscriptions. The root node itself has no subscriptions. You cannot skip a level in a query. If you want to show a list of all subscriptions across all users, you will need to have a list of all subscriptions in the database.

Comment: Then I need to create another key called all-subscriptions & add all the programs to that Ir-respective of the user. So that i can populate all the programs or is their any other ways to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your `mRef` variable refers to, but this is all that I needed:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RecyclerView view = new RecyclerView(this);
    setContentView(view);

    view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/36299197").child("subscriptions/obama@gmsil,com");

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Program, ProgramVH> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Program, ProgramVH>(Program.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, ProgramVH.class, ref) {
        @Override
        public void populateViewHolder(final ProgramVH programViewHolder, Program program, int position) {
            System.out.println("populateViewHolder for position "+position+" with program "+program);
            programViewHolder.title.setText(program.getTitle());
            programViewHolder.level.setText(""+program.getLength()); // coerce to string to prevent android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
        }
    };
    view.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Since I use a stock layout, I modified the view holder a bit to:

```
public static class ProgramVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView title;
    protected TextView level;

    public ProgramVH(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        this.level = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
    }
}
```

I added an [`Activity36299197`](https://github.com/puf/firebase-stackoverflow-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebasedemo/stackoverflow/Activity36299197.java) to my [sample repo](https://github.com/puf/firebase-stackoverflow-android) for it. If you start the app and select the Activity36299197 from the initial list, you'll see the data from the JSON you posted.

[image: screenshot of RecyclerView on Android device]

Comment: I did some debugging with `mRef` variable & Updated the Question!

Comment: It would be really helpful if you add the complete information to the question straight away. I can't keep coming back to it and scan for updates.