# OR clause in firebase java android

Tags: java, android, firebase, where-clause

Does anyone know how I can do a common "OR" like in a where clause, in firebase?

I need to do that in the query, because I am sending the query to an adapter. So, i mean, I cannot add a listener and check one value and then another. I need to have the complete query pointing to that result in my query.

What I have is something like:

```
chat1:
   user1Id: "1"
   user2Id: "2"
   bothUsers: "1_2"

chat2:
   user1Id: "2"
   user2Id: "4"
   bothUsers: "2_4"
```

I need to get all the chats of the user whose id is "2". I am trying to do a query like:

```
userLogged = 2;
Query queryRef = firebase.orderByChild("user2Id").equalTo(userLogged);
```

However it will only get the chats when the user 2 is in the user2Id position. But in the example above, when the user 2 is in the user1Id (chat2) it won't get. And I need to get it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a NoSQL database you will often have to model your data for the way your app needs it (see this article for a good explanation on [NoSQL Data Modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)). So if you need a list of all chats for a specific user, store that list:

```
/userChats
  user1Id
    chat1: true
  user2Id
    chat1: true
    chat2: true
  user4Id
    chat2: true
```

This process is called denormalizing and it is covered in the article I linked above, in the [Firebase documentation on structuring data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-indices) and in this [blog post](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm reading the article now and it's being helpful. However I still have one doubt: in this case, how can I get the attributes that I have for chat, like chat Id and the users that are present in the chat? How could I do a query to get that information?

Comment: I am caring all the information from the chat and putting it in this new list of chats. Instead of just having: (chat1: true) for example, I am putting just chat1 and its attributes under it. It's working properly, but I am just not sure if it okay to carry all the information like this. Is it okay?

Comment: You'd loop over the keys and then "join" in the actual Chat data. If you're using FirebaseUI, have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559171/coupling-firebaserecyclerviewadapter-to-a-boolean-string-map-entry

Comment: This answer that you sent me the link is exactly what I was looking for! It works perfectly now :D .. thank you so much!

Comment: I just have one more question, I am struggling here to get a value "different from". For example, I want to set the adapter to get all users, except the logged one. so I want to query something like: Query queryRef = firebaseRef.orderByChild("user").DIFFERENT_FROM(userLogged). I know this DIFFERENT_FROM command doesn't exist, but it's just to illustrate what I want to do. I know I could query all users and then check the data snapshot to see if it's different from the logged user, however I need to send this queryRef to my adapter. How can I do this?