# Performance Issues with Boolean List of Data in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have de-normalized data as suggested in the docs in firebase database. With a list of groups a user is a member of I am storing in the :value. However, with the use of [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34561726/1820644) of using this list in FirebaseUI, while scrolling through a large list, attaching listeners is causing a performance bottleneck.

Is there any way listeners are not attached each time when user scrolls the list? Or any other way to reduce performance issues with a large list of booleans referencing another location in the database?

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#child-events

You should only have to attach one listener, `child_changed`

> ```
> ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
>         Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
>
>         // A new comment has been added, add it to the displayed list
>         Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
>
>         // ...
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
>         Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
>
>         // A comment has changed, use the key to determine if we are displaying this
>         // comment and if so displayed the changed comment.
>         Comment newComment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
>         String commentKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
>
>         // ...
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
>         Log.d(TAG, "onChildRemoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
>
>         // A comment has changed, use the key to determine if we are displaying this
>         // comment and if so remove it.
>         String commentKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
>
>         // ...
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
>         Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
>
>         // A comment has changed position, use the key to determine if we are
>         // displaying this comment and if so move it.
>         Comment movedComment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
>         String commentKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
>
>         // ...
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
>         Log.w(TAG, "postComments:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
>         Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed to load comments.",
>                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     }
> };
> ref.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it will not help it with the boolean values as list and retrieving list item details from the key by attaching value event listeners in onBindViewHolder / populateViewHolder in firebase ui..