# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with 2 children

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have this database:

```
Database:
   X:{
     UserID:{
        UNIQUE_ID_GENERATED_BY_PUSH_METHOD:{
          x:"hello",
          y:"hey there!"
       }
        UNIQUE_ID_2_GENERATED_BY_PUSH_METHOD:{
          x:"what's up?",
          y:"Nothing Much"
       }
   }  
    UserID2:{
        UNIQUE_ID_GENERATED_BY_PUSH_METHOD:{
          x:"bye",
          y:"Have a nice day!"
       }
        UNIQUE_ID_2_GENERATED_BY_PUSH_METHOD:{
          x:"what's up?",
          y:"Nothing Much"
       }
   }  
}
```

However, my `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is empty with this database as I pass this `DatabaseReference` to my `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`:

```
DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("X");
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Campaign, CampaignHolder>(Campaign.class, R.layout.recyclerview_template, CampaignHolder.class, ref) {
//...
}
```

It works fine when I don't have each post under the user's `userID`. So if I remove the parent `UserID`, my `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` won't be empty.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're trying to accomplish. But if you're looking how to display the information from a "linked entity" (`x` in the sample JSON) in the view, read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559171/coupling-firebaserecyclerviewadapter-to-a-boolean-string-map-entry

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't think that's related; the Boolean values were just an example.  I'll edit my question to be clearer

Comment: With this reference, your `populateViewHolder()` will be called for each user. You use a `Campaign` class, which seems like it's not the same. You'll need a `User` class that contains the campaigns.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it turns out I forgot to change the `DatabaseReference`, thanks

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen wait, nevermind it's not working. But can't the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter just go 2 childs down?

Comment: Flattening nested data is not currently a feature. If you think there is common demand for it, file a [feature request on the Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues). I haven't seen this request before though, so you might be better off building this on your own fork of the repo.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it's going to take me a while to solve this then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flattening nested data is not currently a feature of FirebaseUI. If you think there is common demand for it, file a [feature request on the Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues). I haven't seen this request before though, so you might be better off building this on your own fork of the repo.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this pull request: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/pull/276
I think it could be what you are looking for: if you index your data, all you have to do is provide it a list of keys to get x and y. See the documentation: https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/7e2be3aed73735e3d4e1a318cf268a5c9db67475/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-with-indexed-data

I think you would have to change your data structure to be something like this:

```
message-keys: {
    uid1: {
        key1: true
        key2: true
    }
    uid2: {
        key1: true
        key2: true
    }
}
messages: {
    key1: {
        x: "bye"
        y: "Have a nice day!"
    }
    key2: {
        x: "what's up?"
        y: "Nothing Much"
    }
}
```

Then you would create a `RecyclerView` like so:

```
new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat, ChatHolder>(Chat.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, ChatHolder.class, ref.child("message-keys").child(uid), ref.child("messages"))
```

Hope this helps!