# Firebase get child of childlist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've created a ListView where it should display all the usernames of the firebase users that exists. But now ive got the problem that i dont know how to get the child of the userID's. Sure i can create an array with the ids in the  database but if more people register on the app it dont do it automaticly. So do you know how to get all childs from a child? It looks like this

```
Root
   iadf09f08asd0fasd
      Infos
         Username: LeagueHans
   i297f9pb2f92
       Infos 
         Username: Julian
   08bfbüqw0efü
       Infos
         Username: Markus
```

From comments:

```
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
root.child("Users")‌​.child(What to write here).child("Infos").child("Username");
```

I dont know how to get the the userid(`iadf09f08asd0fasd`) as a child.

Comment: `Root` node you are creating or its something like `fir-xxxxxx`?

Comment: DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(What to write here).child("Infos").child("Username");

I dont know how to get the the userid(iadf09f08asd0fasd) as a child

Answer (score 2):

When you run a query on a location, you will get a subset of the nodes immediately under that location. You cannot retrieve lower-level children under that.

So either you will have to retrieve all data and then just handle the user name client-side or (preferably) you'll need to change your data model to fit better with your use-case.

## Only use the username

```
root.child("Users")‌​.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) {
        String username = snapshot.child("Infos/Username).getValue(String.class);
    }
    ...
```

This will work, but means that you're retrieving more data than you need. This is one of the many reasons that Firebase recommends that you don't nest data unless you always need it in combination.

The alternative is to:

## Use a data model that matches your use-case

I often recommend that in Firebase you model the screens of your app. So if you want to show a list of user names in your app, you should keep a list of user names in your database:

```
Usernames
   iadf09f08asd0fasd: "LeagueHans"
   i297f9pb2f92: "Julian"
   08bfbüqw0efü: "Markus"
```

Now you can get just the user names with:

```
root.child("Usernamess")‌​.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) {
        String username = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Wow thank you!
But do you know if i can display the usernames from the first method in a FirebaseListAdapter? Because its a String :/

Comment: It would've helped if you'd shared your adapter in that case. :-/ But yes, you can override `parseSnapshot()` and just return the username there - similar (though not completely the same) to what I've done here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34561726/209103.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

The firebase `addValueEventListener` will get trigger at every time whenever your database get changed so use this to retrieve your data.

```
mReference.child("Root").child("Infos").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot eventSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                YourModel mModel = eventSnapshot.getValue(YourModel.class);
                Log.e("NAME " ,""+ mModel);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please explain what this does for future newbies to know what this does

Comment: Before start using firebase, If you are going to use Firebase then you should knows about all the method and query of it.. read documentation to work on, without that you will never get to know how it works.

Comment: But newbies won't know exactly what you're doing. You can't just give code, if what you're saying is correct, then EVERY answer should just be code no matter the tag, since in your case "He should know the methods and query of it", which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: It is still missing information. And I have every right to encourage you to fix your answer and I have every right to keep my downvote until it's improved

Comment: I dont want an eventlistener i want to know how i can display all the users child when you start the activity

Comment: Using this you will get the list of child and then use that list to display your child data.

Comment: Ouh im sry im really bad at explaining things!
In my database i got the root than a child called users and in this child there are all users with their userid and in this child again there is the child info and in this child there is the username i want

But i cant just write child(users).child(id) cause everyone gots a different one i need something that i cann display the username from all users

I dont know if you can understand this im trying my best

Comment: I've found a really nice tutorial about it but it is for swift
https://youtu.be/qD582zfXlgo?t=3m56s
Maybe u will understand what i mean when ur watching this
Its with timelink so you will instantly see what i need