# Firebase Merge Reference ID Data with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

below is my JSON Structure of Firebase Database.

[image: JSON Database Structure]

From above data, I want to join Users and Posts using authorId
how can I merge this two schema into one and add them to recyclerview.

Comment: For an example of joining data with FirebaseUI, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559171/coupling-firebaserecyclerviewadapter-to-a-boolean-string-map-entry

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for comment, I also wanted to know
Is it ok to use **DatabaseReference** _inside_ populateViewHolder()?
Is it **best practice**? If yes, then what if I have more than one key ref in JSON Schema, Do I need to create **DatabaseReference for each** of those to get their respective value in populateViewHolder(), will it affect recycler view's performance?

Comment: Everything you do affects performance. Yes, you will need to load each item separately. That is not as slow as you may think. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786