# Firebase RecyclerView Adapter - Join Query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to get UserID from one table(homeaccount) and get the user's info from another table(userinfo) using the user id. I tried to do it by the following way. But, it is overwriting the cardviews one on top of another.

```
databaseReference.child("homeaccount/"+globalSharedPrefs.getUserDetail("currenthome")+"/Users")
.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String str_iteration_uid = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        userQuery = databaseReference.child("userinfo").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(str_iteration_uid);
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<HomeUsers, HomeUsersViewHolder>(
                HomeUsers.class,
                R.layout.cardview_manage_user,
                HomeUsersViewHolder.class,
                userQuery
        ){
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final HomeUsersViewHolder viewHolder, final HomeUsers model, int position) {
                //viewHolder.setFirstName(model.getFirstName());
                //viewHolder.setProfilePicture(model.getProfilePicture());
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: @james whats the edit for?

Comment: You're resetting the adapter of your recycler view for every user. So that is the reason it only shows the latest user. For an example of how to join data client-side with FirebaseUI, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559171/coupling-firebaserecyclerviewadapter-to-a-boolean-string-map-entry

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did go through it. I didnt get it. Please help with this specific query.